# SQL server query, strange behaviour

Tags: sql, sql-server

I've this SQL Query:

```
SELECT  UserChiamante.UserId as UserId

FROM    Something

WHERE   Something AND
        UserChiamante.UserId = ChiamanteInterno.UtenteId
```

The result is something like this:

```
_________________
|     UserId    |       
|_______________|
|     1008      |
|---------------|
|     1022      |
|---------------|
|     1032      |
|_______________|
```

And it's ok.
But if i change the query in:

```
SELECT  UserChiamante.UserId as UserId

FROM    Something

WHERE   Something AND
        UserChiamante.UserId != ChiamanteInterno.UtenteId
```

I expect a different Result, but i get some strange result like:

```
_________________
|     UserId    |       
|_______________|
|     1008      |
|---------------|
|     1022      |
|---------------|
|     1032      |
|---------------|
|     1258      |
```

The ID 1258 it's ok because i dont have this ID in ChiamateInterno table, but the other 3 its in ChiamateInterno Table (obv, u can see from the first version of the query).

Obv "UtenteId" its a foreign key for "UserId"

So why this record are selected??

Comment: Your query is syntactically incorrect. You must provide the full query for better understanding the problem.

Comment: Can you please expand the `Something` and the `Something`?
You are implementing a join and possibly try to do an outer join, but instead you get almost a Cartesian product as every row will be joined by almost every other row in the other table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should really show more of your query and sample results.

But, I'm pretty sure the problem is that you don't fully understand joins.  After all, you are not even using correct `join` syntax with an `on` clause.  A good guess is that you want to exclude things in the second table.

For your query do:

```
where UserChiamante.UserId not in (select UtenteId from ChiamanteInterno)
```

Of course the exact syntax and structure might be different, depending on the rest of the query.

Answer (score 0):

I presume that the first query looks something like:

```
SELECT  UserChiamante.UserId as UserId
FROM    UserChiamante, ChiamanteInterno
WHERE   UserChiamante.UserId = ChiamanteInterno.UtenteId;
```

First, rewrite this as an explicit `JOIN`:

```
SELECT  UserChiamante.UserId as UserId
FROM    UserChiamante JOIN ChiamanteInterno ON
        UserChiamante.UserId = ChiamanteInterno.UtenteId;
```

Then I presume you need an outer join in your second query. So try:

```
SELECT  UserChiamante.UserId as UserId
FROM    UserChiamante LEFT JOIN ChiamanteInterno ON
        UserChiamante.UserId = ChiamanteInterno.UtenteId
WHERE   UserChiamante.UserId IS NULL;
```

Or probably the other way around.